# I need the data received from the XML file to be saved to the database. I wrote the code, but I can't save the received data to the database:

Tags: java, xml, spring, jpa

```
@Autowired
  private MyRepository myRepo; //Inject your repo in service


  @Override
  public void parseSnFile(String fileName) {    

      //...

      for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
             Node node = list.item(temp);
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 Element element = (Element) node;
                 String id = element.getElementsByTagName("uid").item(0).getTextContent();
                 String lastName = element.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent();
                 String snType = element.getElementsByTagName("snType").item(0).getTextContent();
                 String programList = element.getElementsByTagName("program").item(0).getTextContent();

                 MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(id, lastName, snType, program); //serealize your data into entity
                 myRepo.save(entity) //saving to database
                 System.out.println(id + " " + lastName + " snType " + snType + " programList " + programList);
```

This code works, but I have a problem. In the XML file, some of the fields related to `lastName` are empty, that is, they have a null value. And when I try to run, I have a `NullPointerException`. How can I set a condition so that the project does not crash, but where the null value was simply a space and the data was written further ...

Comment: This code works, but I have a problem. In the XML file, some of the fields related to lastName are empty, that is, they have a null value. And when I try to run, I have a NullPointerException. How can I set a condition so that the project does not crash, but where the null value was simply a space and the data was written further ...

Comment: maybe it should look like something like:

Comment: You can [Edit] your question and add all details.

Comment: String lastName = ?;                                                                                                                     
    if(lastName != null) {                                                                                                                
                  lastName = element.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent(); }

Comment: How does your XML look like? I bet you can map it with JAXB and dont' have to parse it by your own

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that it defaults to empty `String`:

```
String lastName = null;
if ((element.getElementsByTagName("lastName") != null) && (element.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0) != null)) {
    String lastName = element.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent();
}
```

Comment: I have two fields in the table - lastName and firstName.
I also think to join the lastName and firstName fields into one column. It also does not work)))) Can you help?))))

Comment: @Alexander do you intend to change the table's structure?

Comment: Yes. i need lastName and firstName to be concatenated in one column - fullName

Comment: @Alexander you can do something like `alter table yourtable add column compositeName text; update yourtable set compositeName = concat(coalesce(concat(firstname, ' '), ''), coalesce(lastName, ''));` and then create an insert and an update `trigger` to enforce the rule for compositeName for future inserts and updates.